# evince: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libatk-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_log_structured_standard

Tags: lookup, symbols

I can't open evince through the command line.  I can do so through the GUI.  When typing 'evince' into the command line I get the error:
[evince: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libatk-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_log_structured_standard]
Any ideas what is going on?  I have no clue.

Answer (score 5):

You need to find the correct libatk package.
I have a similar problem and I solved it.

> /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_log_structured_standard

Just run

```
yum install pango-devel
```